# Check if part of output has already been sent in PHP

Tags: php

In PHP, is there a (ready-made) way to check if a part of the output has already been sent to the client?

I know that with `headers_sent()` you can check if the headers have already been sent, but I also want to check if **any output** has been sent (so that e.g. the HTTP header `Content-Length` > 0).

*(Notice that* `ob_start()` *starts output buffering from the moment when it is called. But third-party systems implementing my code might already have sent output, thus output buffering is unusable as far as I know.)*

Comment: *get_headers() returns an array with the headers sent by the server in response to a HTTP request.* (http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could wrap your own ob_start around everything else and flush it when you decide to. It works even if other ob_start's and flushes are inside. Take this example :

```
ob_start();
[...]
//some 3rd party app which is included on the way
    [...]
    ob_start();
    [...]
    ob_flush(); //at this moment the buffer isn't flushed to the client
                //but to the parent ob_start, which is yours, so no output
                //is sent yet
 [...]
 //ok, we're done, we can output now
 ob_flush();
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP in most cases sends headers to Apache only with some content or on the end of script execution. So, if headers are sent, some content is sent too. Furthemore, as I understand, `Content-Length` is calculated anyway after the script execution.

Comment: I don't quite agree. Not every HTTP response has a message body. Think e.g. of a redirection. It sends only an HTTP status code and a Location-header. So not every response actually contains actual 'content'. And the response is not sent by PHP but by the server. PHP only lets you modify some headers etc.

Comment: _sends headers_ means that PHP sends them to Apache. I`m sorry if I described this ambiguously. As of your example, when script sets `Location` header, it then anyway ends execution. In most cases, with `exit` or `die`. So, after this, as I described, headers are sent. Note `or on the end of script execution` in my message.